# Getting "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" when trying compare list

Tags: python

I am wondering what I am doing wrong in the code below, I'm basically trying to take two lists that a user inputs and using union to make a new list with common elements from the 2 user lists. How ever once I reach the union part is when I get the error.

My code:

```
import random
import sys
import os

clear = lambda: os.system('cls')

x = 1

listA = []
listB = []
commlist = []

clear()
ammA = int(raw_input("How many elements do you want for your first     set?"))


clear()
while ammA > 0:
    listA.append(int(raw_input("Element %i :" %(x))))
    x = x+1
    ammA = ammA-1


clear()
ammB = int(raw_input("How many elements do you want for your second     set?"))

x = 1

clear()
while ammB > 0:
    listB.append(int(raw_input("Element %i :" %(x))))
    x = x+1
    ammB = ammB-1

commlist = list(set(ammA).union(set(ammB)))

clear()
print("Your two list are:")
print(listA)
print(listB)
print("The common elements are:")
print(commlist)
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Bob/Documents/Intro To Python/Practice/Comparitor.py", line 39, in <module>
    commlist = list(set(ammA).union(set(ammB)))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Surely the [mcve] is `set(1)`; compare to `set((1,))`. Did you mean to make the *lists* into sets?

Comment: It is ammA and ammB that are integers, you should be using the lists listA and listB with union.

Comment: UGH I'm so dumb, idk how i missed that for so long, ig I'm just tired lol I was looking at this code for a good amount of time I'm sad to say and didn't see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to create sets from the integer variables used to determine how many elements to put in the lists, not from the lists themselves. Try this instead:

```
>>> listA = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> listB = [1,3,5,7,9]
>>> set(listA).union(set(listB))
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9}
```

Note, however, that for the *common* elements you probably want `intersection` instead of `union`.

```
>>> set(listA).intersection(set(listB))
{1, 3, 5}
```